# « No true Scotsman » en français

Tags: vocabulaire, expressions

L'expression « *No true Scotsman* » (« Pas un vrai Écossais ») est un procédé rhétorique fallacieux utilisé pour réfuter un exemple.

Par exemple (emprunté a [Wikipédia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_true_Scotsman)),

> « Aucun Écossais ne met de sucre dans son porridge.
>   — Mon oncle Angus aime mettre du sucre dans son porridge.
>   — Oui, mais aucun *vrai* Écossais ne mettrait de sucre dans son porridge. »

Ce procédé est évidemment aussi utilisé en français. L'article français de Wikipédia traduit l'expression par « Sophisme du vrai Écossais ». Cependant, l'article français est une traduction plus ou moins directe de la version anglaise. Et une recherche Google pour « Sophisme du vrai Ecossais » renvoie seulement 50 000 liens, et les 9 premiers sont des liens Wikipédia vers d'autres sophismes, et « Sophisme du vrai Écossais » n'y apparait que comme article connexe.

C'est pourquoi je me demandais si l'expression « vrai Écossais » était vraiment utilisée en francais (dans la vie courante — comme « pente savonneuse », un des sophismes apparaissant dans Wikipedia — ou en philosophie/logique). Sinon, quelle est l'expression qui exprime la même idée ? Par exemple, y a-t-il un « sophisme du vrai Breton » ou du « vrai Basque » ?

Answer (score 2):

#### Vrai Écossais

L'article Wikipédia mis en lien explique bien que ce sophisme porte sur le *procédé* utilisé, non sur le terme « Écossais ». Le nom est dû à son origine, raison pour laquelle on retient l'Écossais pour exemple, mais il est déclinable à l'infini.

> Le sophisme du vrai Écossais ou aucun vrai Écossais (en anglais No true Scotsman) est **un procédé rhétorique fallacieux** utilisé pour réaffirmer une généralisation qui a pourtant été réfutée, en niant la validité du contre-exemple. Il **affirme que le contre-exemple donné est invalide car il n'appartient pas vraiment à la catégorie** que l'on cherchait à généraliser.<sup>1</sup>

Pour résumer, cela revient à répondre : « Ton contre-exemple n'est pas valide parce que ce n'est pas un *vrai* X » où X est la catégorie que l'on cherche à généraliser.

A-t-on des exemples avec les Écossais dans la langue française ? Non, pas à ma connaissance, mais il est vrai que c'est une culture dont nous sommes plus éloignés que les Anglo-Saxons.

Ce sophisme peut cependant être utilisé avec n'importe quel groupe d'individus (Breton, Basque, Ch'ti, catho, …). Théoriquement, il peut même être utilisé avec des animaux (Exemple ridicule : Tous les chiens passent leur temps à se renifler le derrière. — Pas le mien. — Tous les *vrais* chiens se reniflent le derrière ») ou des inanimés (pas d'idée d'exemple).

Toutefois, dans tous ces autres cas, le procédé ne change pas, et retient par conséquent son nom d'origine : le sophisme du vrai Écossais.

#### Pente savonneuse

Concernant l'exemple de la pente savonneuse, un coup d'œil rapide à [l'article Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pente_savonneuse) permet de se rendre compte que, si le sophisme emprunte une expression courante pour nom, il n'est nullement relié à celle-ci dans son usage.

L'expression peut décrire n'importe quel état de fait : « si on commence comme ça, on va se retrouver sur une pente savonneuse », « tu es sur une pente glissante. »

Au contraire, le sophisme est toujours fallacieux (ce qui est souvent le cas d'un [sophisme](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sophisme)) :

> La **pente savonneuse**, également appelée **pente fatale** ou **pente glissante**, est un sophisme qui consiste à prétendre qu'un compromis donné doit être refusé car il amorcerait une réaction en chaîne de conséquences de plus en plus graves [...].
>
> Le caractère fallacieux de ce sophisme vient du fait que l'auteur néglige l'influence de phénomènes régulateurs, tendant spontanément à rétablir l'équilibre à mesure que la thèse adverse gagne du terrain.
>
> Contrairement à son équivalent anglais de *slippery slope*, ce terme désigne toujours un raisonnement fallacieux.

Il est donc logique que « pente glissante » ait un grand nombre de résultats, mais la plupart d'entre eux concernent l'usage de l'expression et non du sophisme.

Il ne faut pas chercher un lien entre le nom du sophisme et sa pertinence dans une langue. En regardant les sophismes proposés par Wikipédia, on constate que la plupart d'entre portent un nom latin, qui est probablement peu connu du grand public.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> L'emphase est mienne.</sub>

Comment: (2/3) On a certainement pas attendu 1975 pour utiliser ce procedes rhetoriques en France et on a argumente sur les "vrais Francais", les "vrais Parisiens", les "vrais catholiques", les "vrais partisans de Napoleon" depuis bien longtemps. La rhetorique et la logique etant etudiees depuis des siecles en France, on peut imaginer sans peine que ce procede rhetorique est aussi designe par une autre expression. Cette autre expression, ou la refutation de son existence, telle est l'objet de ma question. D'ailleurs, l'expression anglaise etant recente, on peut se demander comment ce sophisme etait...

Comment: (3/3) designe chez les Anglo-Saxons avant 1975. (Desole pour l'ordre des commentaires, je ne pensais pas qu'il serait si long).

Comment: (1/3) Merci pour le commentaire. Malheureusement, je ne suis pas sur que cela repond a ma question. Je ne dis pas qu'il faudrait a tout prix traduire l'expression, ou qu'un francais ne pourrait pas comprendre l'expression un vrai ecossais, mais qu'au vu de l'article Wikipedia qui est une copie de l'article anglais, et de la recherche Google (compare avec une recherche pour "pente savonneuse" ou "argument ad hominem"), j'etais tente de penser que l'expression etait un anglicisme. Probablement recent puisque l'origine de l'expression "No true Scotsman" en anglais date de seulement 40 ans.

Comment: Remarque que "pente savonneuse" est seulement un exemple dans lequel l'expression que je cherche est employe.

Comment: Pour preciser ma question, si j'apprenais que les Japonais utilisent depuis peu la traduction litterale de "tomber de Charybde en Scylla" pour dire aller de mal en pis, j'imaginerais que c'est une expression empruntee a l'anglais et je me demanderais quelle est l'expression originale japonais (il s'avere que c'est quelquechose comme "aller du tigre au loup").

Comment: (1/2) Les exemples donnés ne correspondent pas : dans le cas des Japonais, on parle d'une expression idiomatique, et oui, chaque langue a les siennes. La « pente savonneuse » est un exemple dangereux car elle peut être l'expression idiomatique ou le nom du sophisme, et Google n'a pas les moyens de distinguer l'un de l'autre. Que le nom du sophisme soit le même qu'en anglais ne me choque pas : il n'était pas nommé avant, un Anglais a donné un exemple utilisant un Écossais, cet exemple a nommé le sophisme. Pourquoi vouloir changer ce nom lors de son passage au français ?

Comment: (2/2) Celui qui décrit le premier une découverte a le privilège de la nommer. Il en a toujours été ainsi en science et nous sommes ici dans la science du raisonnement et du langage. La question revient pour moi à demander pourquoi l'amanite tue-mouche ne s'appelle pas amanite mange-guêpe dans une autre langue. Ce type de changement a généralement tendance à faire obstacle à la compréhension et peut être difficile à justifier.