# « Salut les vrais ! »

Tags: oral, interjections, substantivation

Il y a longtemps, une polémique éclata au sujet d'une série de [publicités](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6-W7ypfJu9k)<sup>1</sup> d'un brasseur canadien ([*Molson*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molson)) qui se terminaient par l'affichage de la phrase suivante :

> [...] [SALUT](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/salut) LES [VRAIS](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vrai) ! [en majuscules dans la publicité]

C'est qu'on dit « [[...] *Molson [citation]*](https://youtu.be/6-W7ypfJu9k?t=25s) » et il n'y a aucune pause entre les deux. Plus tôt, dans un effet de voix hors-champs d'une des(2) publicités, [on entend](https://youtu.be/6-W7ypfJu9k?t=1m11s) aussi « *Molson te salue* ».

- Est-ce (*salut les vrais!*) une compagnie qui se nomme au micro avant une interjection ?
  Est-ce une figure de style ? Comment ça s'analyse ?<sup>2</sup>
- De quels *vrais* s'agit-il ici ? Est-ce courant sans complément, en
  substantif ? Est-ce relié à ce qu'on retrouve dans une autre [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/16015) ?

---

<sub>1. Il y a deux publicités accompagnées de deux parodies permettant (d'en rire) de réfléchir à la deuxième question.</sub>
<sub>2. On comprend fort bien qu'il s'agit de la langue parlée et que dans le domaine de la publicité (télévisée) on s'autorise de beaucoup de liberté. On est simplement curieux de l'emploi qu'on fait de la langue et on veut nommer ce qu'on constate.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dans l'expression "salut les vrais!", "les vrais" est interprété comme l'expression anglaise "true blue" — laquelle peut être un adjectif (loyal) ou un nom (une personne loyale). Puisque Molson est une brasserie originaire de Montréal et que le Québec accorde beaucoup d'importance à son identité nationale, la publicité fait une référence un peu patriotique — ce qui est très commun au Québéc dans le monde de la pub et de l'image de marque (voir: "[Ici c'est Pepsi!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XYpihSopmQw)"). Le Québec francophone s'associe encore à la "working class", d'où les images dans la pub; la bière étant considérée comme une récompense après de l'effort physique dans la culture populaire, le lien entre le produit et les images est assez fort.

Je crois que la pub dit "Molson salue les vrais", et que le texte ("salut les vrais!") est ladite salutation textuelle.